# How do I make a developer app on a Facebook page account?

Tags: facebook

I have registered a Facebook account only for my website's Facebook page.

Then I wanted to make a developers’ Facebook app, so I registered on http://developers.facebook.com and verified my account.

On the developers’ page, when I go to *App* menu item to create an app, I get redirected to first page without any notification or error message.

Is this a bug or what? How can I make an app on this account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use a personal account. There is no way around it.

> 'Business' or advertising accounts can't manage apps - if at some
>   point in the past you were able to create an app using a business
>   account this is a bug or loophole and shouldn't have been possible -
>   only real verified user accounts should be able to create and manage
>   apps.
>
> If you need to share ownership of the app between multiple people you
>   can do so either via making a Facebook Group an admin and adding the
>   other admin users to that group, or by adding the users directly via
>   the
>   [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#props)
>   or the 'Roles' tab of the App settings: [image: Role management popup with 'Create Group' option]
>
> You can also specify a business account which will manage the ads for
>   an app in the app settings - on the Advanced tab - but this is the
>   only supported connection between apps and business accounts -

[image: screenshot here]

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account